# Do any precolumbian board games survive?

Tags: history

A number of board games survive to the present day from quite ancient times in the Old World: mancala, go, even the physical components of the game of Ur survived (though we don't know the rules).

Do any board games survive from the New World that predate Columbus?

Comment: I have to ask: how much research did you do before asking this? Because the second Google result for the title of this question appears to adequately answer it.

Comment: @murgatroid99, apparently "precolumbian" is the magic word here.  I tried searching with other terms, like "new world" and "americas", but got too much noise.  Somehow "precolumbian" didn't occur to me till writing the question.

Answer (score 4):

After reading [this article](http://www.cyningstan.com/post/1123/games-around-the-world-pre-columbian-america) I could find several references to games played during the precolumbian era.

For some of them the rules are unknown but here is the list (to be completed) :

1. [Patolli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patolli) played by Teotihuacanos, Toltecs, etc. Before Christ !
2. [Bul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bul_%28game%29)
3. [Awithlaknakwe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awithlaknakwe)
4. Totolospi